# Mix plot with Cos and Points

Tags: plotting

With `Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]` I do

[image]

And I can add a horizontal line by dowing `Plot[{Cos[x], 1/2}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`.

[image]

How do I add some specific points, P0(0,0), P1(1,1), P2(2,2)?

Comment: Look up `Epilog` and `Point[]`.

Comment: May I ask for an example (I'm just beginning with Mathematica)?

Comment: Or, use `ListPlot` to plot the points, and `Show` to combine the result with your `Cos` plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example points use the intersection of the two curves

```
pts = {x, 1/2} /. Solve[{Cos[x] == 1/2, 0 < x < 2 Pi}, x]

(*  {{Pi/3, 1/2}, {(5*Pi)/3, 1/2}}  *)

Plot[{Cos[x], 1/2}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Epilog -> {Red , AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ pts},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.9, 0.2}]]
```

[image]